# Get rid of space inside p tag when using a span tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I bring my span immediately below the text inside the p tag

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/bobbyfrancisjoseph/H4U7r/

I am pasting the HTML code also here

```
<p class="now-p" style="color:#000;">IN THEATERS NOW
    <br>
<span style="font-size:13px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Trailers,Songs,Ratings,Reviews & Comments</span>

    </br>
</p>
```

The CSS is as follows.

```
.now-p {
    padding-bottom:10px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    color:#91979e;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:36px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

I am trying to make the output look something like this:

```
                  IN THEATERS NOW 
     Trailers,Songs,Ratings,Reviews & Comments
```

Now there is a space after IN THEATERS NOW . I am not able to get rid of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The span *is* immediately below the text, it's the line height of the first line of the text that causes the spacing between the lines.

Set the line height of the first text to bring them together. (And you can use padding to indent the second line instead of spaces.)

HTML:

```
<p class="now-p" style="color:#000;">
  <span class="header">IN THEATERS NOW</span>
  <br>
  <span class="text">Trailers,Songs,Ratings,Reviews & Comments</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.now-p {
  padding-bottom:10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  color:#91979e;
  text-align:left;
  font-weight:bold;
}

.now-p .header {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.now-p .text {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H4U7r/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try removing your break tags and add this to your css:

```
.now-p span{
    display:block;
    font-size:13px;
}
```

Comment: That seems to give the desired effect, but how does that work? Why does the block invade the line height of the first line?

Comment: The <br /> tag is the issue, you should really avoid using <br /> tags for layout.

This turns the <span> tag into a block element and pushes it onto the next line. The spacing between the two lines can then be set with either line-height or padding on the <span>.

Answer (score 1):

The `space` is due to the `<br>` in the line under the `<p>`. If you put `IN THEATERS NOW<br/>` with no spaces, there won't be any more problem.

This might not be the best way to achieve what you want. But I hope it'll help to understand why you had the problem.

Comment: I see no difference at all when I try that.

Answer (score 0):

use CSS `line-height`

```
.now-p {
    line-height: 15px;
}
```